# Why are http headers not set when I use proxypass on apache2.2

Tags: mod-proxy, apache-2.2

I have an apache2.2 server with mod_proxy and mod_headers installed.  On a request running with a `ProxyPass` directive, none of the `Header set` directives work, ie the header's aren't set in the response.

However if I remove the `ProxyPass` directive the headers are set.  Is there some configuration that disables setting headers when using mod_proxy?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?  I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: Sorry no, we ended up moving to nginx

Comment: Did a bit more searching, and I found a solution. Will post for others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Despite the [Apache mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/de/mod/mod_headers.html) doc saying that it does not matter where the Header line goes, it apparently does.  The only way I could get the header added was to put it in the same location scope as the proxy pass.

I initially had the proxy pass defined in the VirtualHost tag directly, but had to move it into the  LocationMatch sub tag.

```
<LocationMatch "/myapp">
    ProxyPass http://1.1.1.1:8080/myapp disablereuse=On
    ProxyPassReverse http://1.1.1.1:8080/myapp
    Header add X-UA-Compatible "IE=7"
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: I'm sure there is a logical reason for this.  Someone with more depth of knowledge in the inner workings of Apache http may know why.

Comment: This deserves a drink.

Comment: The ProxyPassReverse line in the example has three forward slashes after http: , but should only have two.